# Google assistant on Google pixel can't find a contact on whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, google-pixel, google-assistant

I have a Google pixel and I Google assistant can't seem to find a specific contact when I say "send a whatsapp message to contact".  The name is spelt correctly, and if I scroll down the whatsapp contact list, it's there.

Other contacts I've tried are fine. 
What could be wrong?